# Error after rake test, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I following the `rails tutorial` by Hartl https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-getting_started_with_testing and installed everything required and so far it works except for whenever I run `rake test`.

The tests run but afterwards I get a series of **errors as shown below**. I have no idea what these are and how to fix them.

Any ideas?

> /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/tmux.rb:35:in
>   `version': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/tmux.rb:194:in
>   `_check_available'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/base.rb:59:in`
>   initialize'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:92:in
>   `new'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:92:in`
>   add'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:64:in
>   `block (2 levels) in detect'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:62:in`
>   each'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:62:in
>   `detect'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:62:in`
>   block in detect'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:61:in
>   `each'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier/detected.rb:61:in`
>   detect'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:105:in
>   `initialize'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:42:in`
>   new'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/notiffany-0.0.6/lib/notiffany/notifier.rb:42:in
>   `connect'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/notifier.rb:11:in`
>   connect'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/guard-2.12.5/lib/guard/notifier.rb:31:in
>   `notify'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/guard-compat-1.2.1/lib/guard/compat/plugin.rb:113:in`
>   notify'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/guard-minitest-2.4.4/lib/guard/minitest/notifier.rb:31:in
>   `notify'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/guard-minitest-2.4.4/lib/guard/minitest/reporter.rb:10:in`
>   report'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/minitest-5.6.1/lib/minitest.rb:638:in
>   `each'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/minitest-5.6.1/lib/minitest.rb:638:in`
>   report'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/minitest-5.6.1/lib/minitest.rb:134:in
>   `run'
>           from /home/cuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/minitest-5.6.1/lib/minitest.rb:56:in`
>   block in autorun'

Comment: please provide your gemlist and your rspec file

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tmux? If not, then I would remove the configuration that tells tmux to notify you once the tests have finished. This configuartion might be in test_helper.rb but it's hard to know without seeing which tutorial you're following.

Comment: I'm using this tutorial here:
https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-getting_started_with_testing

i don't have tmux installed however.

Answer (score 0):

Installing tmux actually solved the issue for me!